# superuser.com reputation point issue- not sure this was thought out very well

Tags: discussion, comments

So, I had an issue, and googled it. I found the solution I needed on this site, and wanted to thank the person who wrote it. I am *not* a regular user of this site, so I created a user account and went to comment.... "Sorry, you need 50 reputation points to leave a comment."

So....as a non-user...you want me to jump through 50 different hoops to tell *your user thanks*???? Who thought this was a good idea? I don't think I'll be returning.

Comment: The many who left derogatory comments forced the change sadly affecting the good few - this happens often : bank cheques and cheque guarantee cards etc etc

Comment: Yanno? This site's been around for more than 8 years. We've had lots of finetuning and time to think about it.  That it works is why you managed to find an answer to start with.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your heart was in the right place.  BTW, it isn't clear when your post attracted the downvotes.  Any it received on the main site were because the subject matter was inappropriate for there.  Any it received here in Meta are just an expression of disagreement with the post.  Don't take it personally.  The site is different from a forum.  The help link at the top of the main site includes a quick tour to explain the basics, and help topics on how the site works.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Exchange doesn't want comments that just say "thanks".
They clutter up the format & turn it into a forum.

### [Stack Exchange is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

It is a Question & Answer site, where each response is intended to be an answer to the question raised, in an overall attempt to promote learning. Comments may be used to provide &/or request clarification, but are not intended to promote conversation.
Comments that are simply "thanks" are very likely to be deleted.

Comments are also liable to be tidied up, erased, once a suitable answer has been found & so should be considered ephemeral & not needed in order to fully understand the question & its accepted answer.

Instead, the correct way to 'thank' the author of a post is to upvote it.
The minimum reputation requirement is to ensure people have sufficient time to learn the basic concept before being able to participate fully, higher reputation leads to greater privileges.

You can find this & much additional useful information in the [Help Pages](https://superuser.com/help)

Comment: Just voted this up - correct as an answer, but downvoted by someone who obviously does not understand how the site works ...